# PHP string format issue

Tags: php, string, format

I have this for pagination on a project.  How can I display the value of `$maxPages` where the `»»` is?  Basically want the numeric value of the `$maxPages` to show.

```
//Add the forward and last buttons
$string .= ($page < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$page+1,$link).'">»</a> ' :' ' ;
$string .= ($i-1 < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$maxPages,$link).'">»»</a> ' : ' ';
```

I have tried a few things with no success.  Assume a format issue is to blame.

Comment: And `$maxPages` isn't giving you the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure it's just simply replacing `»»` with `$maxPages`

```
//Add the forward and last buttons
$string .= ($page < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$page+1,$link).'">»</a> ' :' ' ;
$string .= ($i-1 < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$maxPages,$link).'">'.$maxPages.'</a> ' : ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $string .= ($page < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$page+1,$link).'">'.$maxPages.'</a> ' :' ' ;
    $string .= ($i-1 < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$maxPages,$link).'">'.$maxPages.'</a> ' : ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$maxPages` *is* the numeric value?

You just *use* it. It doesn't get any simpler.

```
$string .= ($i-1 < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$maxPages,$link).'">' . $maxPages . '</a> ' : ' ';
```